# How to reset Action Bar Search after Searching?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created an action bar Search in the action bar menu. 
Well, I am trying to make it go to its normal state if I click a go button or a click anywhere on the screen. Here is my code :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) menu.findItem(
            R.id.menuSearch).getActionView();

    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {


            menuItem.collapseActionView();

            // Do something when collapsed
            return true; // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            //editText.clearFocus();


            return true; // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

It works well. But, It doesn't go to its normal state. I used this function

```
            menuItem.collapseActionView();
```

But, no use. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
    menuItem.collapseActionView();
```

inside

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The framework calls onMenuItemCollapsed() to *notify* your code that the search view has been collapsed.  A call to "menuItem.collapseActionView()" does no good in that method body.  Your calls to collapseActionView() should be in the code where you want to force the view to be collapsed, such as a keystroke handler for the Go button.